# Error when Creating a Contract - related to Mapping

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, remix

When I create a ABC_Creator Contract.   It gives the following error.   The code works fine for the intent.   Wondering why is this error showing up, what is the invalid opcode and what can be done to get rid of it.   Thanks,

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract ABC {

    bytes32 public name;
    uint public value;

    function ABC(bytes32 _name, uint _val) public {
        name = _name;
        value = _val;
    }
}

contract ABC_Creator {

    ABC localABC;
    mapping (bytes32 => address[]) public abcMap;
    event Log(bytes32, uint);

    function createABC(bytes32 _name, uint _val) public {
        localABC = new ABC(_name, _val);
        abcMap[_name].push(localABC);
    }

    function getABCList(bytes32 _name) public {

        uint len = abcMap[_name].length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Log(ABC(abcMap[_name][i]).name(), ABC(abcMap[_name][i]).value());
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled around with it and found nothing obviously wrong with the contract, so I think you might focus on the behind-the-scenes method you're using to call the contract (not shown).

Your code is compact and I found myself strained to clearly understand what to expect. In particular, the `uint _val` that both contracts want could be a source of confusion.

You can *easily* generate the invalid OPCODE by walking off the end of an array. So, you need to be careful what you ask for.

Consider:

```
 1. ABC_Creator.createABC("rob",10)
 2. ABC_Creator.abcMap("rob",10)

Invalid Opcode. 

 3. ABC_Creator.abcMap("rob",0)

address: 0xf71...
```

What happened?

It took a `localABC("rob",10)` (convertable to `0xf71....`) and pushed it on to the array in `abcMap` at "`rob`", meaning there is now a 1-row array in `abcMap["rob"]`. So, it's okay to ask for the first row of `abcMap["rob"]` but it's not okay to ask for a different row. You can confirm that with a little function to `return abcMap[_name].length;`

What happened to the `10`? It was passed to the `ABC` at `0xf71...` as instructed.

Main takeaway. Take a close look at the offending request. Is it reasonable?

Here it is working:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @RobHitchens.  Thanks for the insight, it was very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

ABC_Creator should have a constructor.

Comment: Thanks @LSong, what would be the content of of the constructor.  Do we have to initialize the mapping, how?